# C# return value from async function

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a C# async function which could return a value.

Current function code:

```
public async void getTwitterFollowerCount()
{
    var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(SharedState.Authorizer);

    var followers = await (from follower in twitterCtx.Friendship where follower.Type == FriendshipType.FollowerIDs && follower.UserID == "15411837" select follower).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (followers != null && followers.IDInfo != null && followers.IDInfo.IDs != null)
    {
        followers.IDInfo.IDs.Count();
    }
}
```

I've been trying something similare to this:

```
public async int getTwitterFollowerCount()
{
    var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(SharedState.Authorizer);

    var followers = await (from follower in twitterCtx.Friendship where follower.Type == FriendshipType.FollowerIDs && follower.UserID == "15411837" select follower).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (followers != null && followers.IDInfo != null && followers.IDInfo.IDs != null)
    {
        return followers.IDInfo.IDs.Count();
    }
}
```

But never got it working. Does someone have a idea, how I could be able to return a value from this async function?

Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: `But never got it working` what were the errors? No reason why this wouldn't work just off a quick glance.

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Dan And by "should" you mean "must".  Returning a non-Task *won't compile*.

Comment: @Dan It can *not return anything at all* (i.e. `void`) but it can't return any non-`Task` type.

Answer (score 3):

Change return type of `getTwitterFollowerCount` to `Task<int>`. Read more at MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx .

Comment: It will work. Even though you return an int, because the function is marked as async, it needs to return a task that will eventually return an int. Try it, you may be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @Hogan see the MSDN page I am referring to -- there is an example that returns exactly `Task<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated,

```
Task<int>
```

is the correct return type.

Also, never have an 'async void' method if you can avoid it since it's impossible to await a method that returns void. The only case where you should do this is with event handlers. Otherwise, always return 'Task'.

Comment: That is indeed true. For the reference:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx